# Can someone explain why carousel starts at slide 3 after a page refresh

Tags: bootstrap-4

This is the code for my carousel. Anytime the site starts or the page is refreshed it starts on Slide 3. It needs to start on Slide 1. Thanks in advance.

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide pointer-event" data-bs-ride="carousel">
        <div class="carousel-indicators">
          <button type="button" data-bs-target="#myCarousel" data-bs-slide-to="0" class="" aria-label="Slide 1"></button>
          <button type="button" data-bs-target="#myCarousel" data-bs-slide-to="1" aria-label="Slide 2" class=""></button>
          <button type="button" data-bs-target="#myCarousel" data-bs-slide-to="2" aria-label="Slide 3" class="active" aria-current="true"></button>
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-inner">
          <div class="carousel-item">
            <img src="images/computers-2652997_1920.jpg" class="d-block w-100 homepics" alt="tech pic">
            <!-- <svg class="bd-placeholder-img" width="100%" height="100%" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" aria-hidden="true" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" focusable="false"><rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#777"></rect></svg> -->

            <div class="container">

              <div class="carousel-caption text-start">
                <h1>Business Analytics</h1>
                <p>Some representative placeholder content for the first slide of the carousel.</p>
                <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="#">Sign up today</a></p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="carousel-item active carousel-item-start">
            <img src="images/hd-wallpaper-2937861_1920.jpg" class="d-block w-100 homepics" alt="tech pic1">

            <div class="container">
              <div class="carousel-caption">
                <h1>Web Development</h1>
                <p>Some representative placeholder content for the second slide of the carousel.</p>
                <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="#">Learn more</a></p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="carousel-item carousel-item-next carousel-item-start">
            <img src="images/business-6657323_1920.jpg" class="d-block w-100 homepics" alt="tech pic2">

            <div class="container">
              <div class="carousel-caption text-end">
                <h1>Corporate Training</h1>
                <p>Some representative placeholder content for the third slide of this carousel.</p>
                <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="#">Browse gallery</a></p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#myCarousel" data-bs-slide="prev">
          <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
        </button>
        <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#myCarousel" data-bs-slide="next">
          <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
        </button>
      </div>
```

tried playing with the different active classes to no avail

Answer (score 0):

```
 <button type="button" data-bs-target="#myCarousel" data-bs-slide-to="2" aria-label="Slide 3" class="active" aria-current="true"></button>
```

as you can see , you have this class:
class="active"

change it in the first slider